# Read a file with latest Date from a folder using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I already have a folder, with the files in it with names below in a specific format i.e. MODEL_RELEASEDATE

File names in the folder named **Smartphone**

```
SmartphoneA_11122012
SmartphoneA_01022013
SmartphoneA_09102013
SmartphoneA_10072012
SmartphoneA_12042012
**SmartphoneB_08282013**
SmartphoneB_04152013
SmartphoneB_08282012
SmartphoneB_01062013
.
.
.
.
and so on
```

I want to write a jquery code where I can use a specific keyword from format, from above list, I will pass the value **SmartphoneA** and I should be able to read the file with the latest release date. Same as in case when I pass the keyword **SmartphoneB**.

If I pass k/w **SmartphoneB**, result should be served from file highlighted above, i.e. **SmartphoneB_08282013**

my current code reads the file name only with specific k/w. I have few alterations to be made.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var metaKeywords=$('meta[name=keywords]').attr("content");//this utility works based upon the keywords on the pages.
    var reqdKeyword = new Array();
    reqdKeyword  = metaKeywords.split(",");
    var randKeyword = reqdKeyword[Math.floor(Math.random() * reqdKeyword.length)];
    var cdnUrl = "http://abc.com/xyz/mobiles/";
    var jsnUrl = ".json?callback=showDetail";
    var finalUrl= cdnUrl.concat(randKeyword.trim()).concat(jsnUrl);


    /*

           Rest of the code goes here

    */


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a server-side code to return you a list of URIs (file names), then you can write JavaScript code to parse it (but in this case it is probably better if your server-side code will return the right name right away based on query string). In the worst case scenario you can place a dir.txt file on the server which will be listing all the files in that folder and e.g. run cron job to update it as needed.

jQuery will have no way to list remote files on the server unless your server supports it in one way or another.

**Update**

Once you have the file you need:

a) tokenize it into an array, e.g. like this

```
 var names = dir.split("\n");
```

b) leave only strings starting with keyword and cut keyword off

```
 names = $(names).map(function(n,i) { 
    return (n.indexOf(keyword) == 0) ?  n.split('_')[1] : null;
 }).get();
```

now you have an array like this ['11122012', '01022013', ...]

c) find max date in this array

```
var dateNum = Math.max.apply( null,
  $.map(names,function(n,i){ return parseInt(
    n.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, function(match, month, day, year) {
            return year + month + day;
        })) 
  }) );
var maxDate = dateNum.toString().replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/,
         function (match, year, month, day) { return month + day + year; }
       );
var fileName = keyword + "_" + maxDate;
```

voila, your fileName contains the name with max date.

There are other ways of doing it, e.g. really parsing the date into Date object. Also, you can simply iterate your files once, without array mapping and Math.max() iterator. As the amount of code wins over speed here, to find the optimal one depends on where you could re-use its bits and pieces without compromising maintainability.

http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/VLB2E/

Comment: I have a server side code which will place the files in the above mentioned format. I only need to read the file with latest date in its name.

Comment: I updated my answer. I suggest you add an update to your question so people who come to this question will understand that you already have the list of files and whether it is a one string of text or JSON array or something else.

Comment: I have updated the question, thanks, and your update seems to be useful. I will get back to you if required. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi @Alex Pakka, My folder has final names as below, your code is not parsing it because the date format is different & inconsistent(if date/month is less than 10, it is not having a "0" in front of it) so it is not working. Can you please update the code at fiddle per this?

**smartphoneA_2005-3-1,
smartphoneA_2007-3-13,
smartphoneA_2008-3-4,
smartphoneA_2009-11-17,
smartphoneA_2010-11-2,
smartphoneB_2010-3-16,
smartphoneB_2012-8-28,
smartphoneB_2013-3-12,
smartphoneC_2014-3-12,
smartphoneC_2014-9-13,
smartphoneC_2011-3-15,
smartphoneC_2004-11-2,
smartphoneC_2007-11-20**

Comment: The file names are rendered from the DB, so I don't have much of control over the dates

Comment: From now on it is as simple as changing regexp and parameters in replace function: replace(/(\d{4})-(\d+)-(\d+)/, function(year,month,day) { ... }

Answer (score 1):

The cool thing about dates is that you can easily sort them if you have the date in "descending" order (i.e., year month day hour second). Using that, we can go through your files to grab just the ones that start with the right prefix, then easily grab the latest one:

```
var filenames = [
        'SmartphoneA_11122012',
        'SmartphoneA_01022013',
        'SmartphoneA_09102013',
        'SmartphoneA_10072012',
        'SmartphoneA_12042012',
        'SmartphoneB_08282013',
        'SmartphoneB_04152013',
        'SmartphoneB_08282012',
        'SmartphoneB_01062013'
    ],
    whichPhone = 'SmartphoneB', // Dummy value, this would come from user interaction or whatever
    possibleFiles = [];

// This goes through your list of filenames and picks out just the ones that match `whichPhone`, then puts them into another array containing a "cleaned-up" date and some other metadata-esque stuff
for (var i = 0, j = filenames.length; i < j; i++) {
    var filename = filenames[i];

    if (filename.indexOf(whichPhone) > -1) {
        possibleFiles.push({
            index: i,
            filename: filename,
            date: parseInt(filename.split('_')[1].replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, function(match, month, day, year) {
                return year + month + day;
            }), 10)
        });
    }
}

// Now we go through the `possibleFiles` and figure out which one has the latest date
var latestFileDate = 0,
    theActualFilenameYouWantFinally;

for (var i = 0, j = possibleFiles.length; i < j; i++) {
    var possibleFile = possibleFiles[i];

    if (possibleFile.date > latestFileDate) {
        latestFileDate = possibleFile.date;
        theActualFilenameYouWantFinally = filenames[possibleFile.index];
    }
}

// And, finally, your result
console.log(theActualFilenameYouWantFinally);
```

EDIT: I didn't use jQuery for this answer because meh, you don't really need jQuery for things like this. Don't get me wrong, John Resig is brilliant, and I use jQuery in almost everything, but `for` loops are damned fast and easy to work with, and stuff like this isn't really jQuery's strong suit anyhow.

Comment: This is the shortest way to make integer out of the DDMMYYYY date I have ever seen. I will +1 for that. But I would actually multiply ymd by powers of 10 as 2012 + 12 + 31 is more than 2013+1+1

Comment: You don't have to multiply, because 20,121,231 is less than 20,130,101 (Which is what you'd get from this code). That's the magic!

Comment: You are correct, of course. Somehow I missed that you add ymd as strings, not as integers.